# SqlDataSource with Guid Parameter

Tags: asp.net

I have this sqlDataSource
@userId is my parameter for Current user in a system .

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="dsProfit" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:DefaultConnection %>" SelectCommand="select name, sum(value) as suma  from AllProfitView where IdUser=@userId group by name  order by sum(value) desc">

</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

In code Behind I have this in Page_Load :

```
 dsProfit.SelectParameters.Add("@userId", cui.getCurrentId());




 public Guid getCurrentId()
        {
            MembershipUser currentUser = Membership.GetUser();
            Guid currentUserId = (Guid)currentUser.ProviderUserKey;
            return currentUserId;
        }
```

when start the page it's blows with ERROR :Must declare the scalar variable "@userId".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `SelectParameter` to your sqlDataSource

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="dsProfit" runat="server"  
ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:DefaultConnection %>"  
SelectCommand="select name, sum(value) as suma  from AllProfitView  
where IdUser=@userId group by name  order by sum(value) desc">
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="userId" Type="String" />
    </SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

and assign likes this

```
  dsProfit.SelectParameters["userId"].DefaultValue =  
  cui.getCurrentId().ToString();
```

Comment: dsProfit.SelectParameters["userId"].DefaultValue =cui.getCurrentId(); - Cannot convert guid to string

Comment: add `Type="Int32"` and par your `GUID` to integer  Tedi , I've edited my answer !

Comment: still cannot  implicityconvert int to string

Answer (score 0):

try to define selectparameter inside of your SqlDatasource

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="dsProfit" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:DefaultConnection %>" SelectCommand="select name, sum(value) as suma  from AllProfitView where IdUser=@userId group by name  order by sum(value) desc">
<SelectParameters>
            <asp:Parameter Name="userId" Type="int32" />
</SelectParameters>

</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

so your parameter is int so convert it to string

```
 dsProfit.SelectParameters["userId"].DefaultValue = cui.getCurrentId().toString();
```

Comment: I think , not `QueryStringParameter` Kemal :) It just get value from query string . But OP want to assign it from code behind .